# The simplest way to solve precedence of operator?

Tags: operator-precedence

The simplest way to solve precedence of operator?

for example 
1+2*3/4%5
I need simplest and logical way to solve it?
"i dont want to use parentheses"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to know operator precedence first, and thier associativity as well.

Here, *, / and % have same precedence but have higher precedence than +. 
Since they all are lef-to-right associative, grouping them results in

1+(((2*3)/4)%5)

If they were right-to-left associative, it would have been

1+(2*(3/(4%5)))

If you don't want to use parenthesis, just make sure you write them in order like:

```
 1+2*3/4%5
 -> 1+6/4%5
 -> 1+1%5 
 -> 1+1
 -> 2
```

I hope you understand.